# How to get data according to range In VUE JS

Tags: vue.js

I am new in Vue Js I want to get the single object in below array in vue. Suppose My **Total Member = 5** then I want Match and get object according to **tour_member_min** & **tour_member_max** and get a single object. 
Or **Total Member = 20 or Bigger the 20 the get last object**

```
[
0: {

    full_day_price: 1000
    half_day_price: 500
    tour_member_max: 5
    tour_member_min: 1

}
1: {full_day_price: 2000
    half_day_price: 1500
    tour_member_max: 6
    tour_member_min: 15
}
2: {
    full_day_price: 3000
    half_day_price: 2000
    tour_member_max: 16
    tour_member_min: 20
}
]
```

Comment: you can do something like this: `yourObject.find(item => item.tour_member_min < 5 && item.tour_member_max <= 5 )`

Comment: in that case If member count is more then 20  then its given zero index data but I need last index (2) data.

Comment: with `find` you will give the condition that if true, that return your object, so try something like `yourObject.find(item => item.tour_member_min >= 20 && item.tour_member_max <= 20 || item.tour_member_max > 20)`

Comment: this has nothing to do with vue.js, does it? this is a normal javascript problem? or are you looking to work with the desired object in the html markup? if this is the case, you could define a computed property which returns the object like @kalidou.diagne described